# How do I take screenshots of web pages using ruby and a unix server?

Tags: ruby, unix, gtk, screenshot, rmagick

I'm trying to programatically create thumbnail images of a large number of web pages that are hosted on my own ruby/rails-based website.

I want to be able to code a stand-alone bit of ruby that looks something like this:

```
require 'awesome-screenshot-maker'

items.each do |id|
  url = "http://foo.com/bar/#{id}"
  shooter = AwesomeScreenshotMaker.new(0.2) # thumbnails are 20% of original
  shooter.capture(url, "/images/thumbnail-#{id}.png")
end
```

I need the awesome-screenshot-maker library (and its dependencies) to be fairly easy to build on Linux, Solaris and Mac OS X. Ideally it will install with a single 'gem install' command.

I've spent the afternoon exploring various options, including [Moz snap shooter](http://www.lilik.it/~mirko/Ruby-GNOME2/moz-snapshooter.rb), [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) and [rbwebkitgtk](http://github.com/danlucraft/rbwebkitgtk/tree/master). They are all in the right area, but none seem to work on all three platforms.

RMagick looks like a possible option if I'm willing to output PDFs from my rails app (instead of web pages), but that strikes me as hacky. It's also very laborious to get RMagic and imagemagick up and running on Mac OS X.

Does such a library exist that can easily be setup on three platforms?

Comment: This question has been asked at least 3 times in the past. Please see the answers to #125951, #686858 and #713938.

Comment: Those answers all refer to python, php or command line applications. I've already explored those options and am keen to find a solid ruby-based solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/) has a Ruby interface and can grab a screenshot using [capture_screenshot(filename,kwargs)](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/ruby/classes/Selenium/Client/GeneratedDriver.html#M000220).

You'd then have to shrink it to a thumbnail.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to try this:

http://www.pageglimpse.com/

Comment: PageGlimpse has closed it's doors.

Answer (score 2):

There is https://github.com/maxwell/screencap which uses phantom.js

Comment: this doesn't work for me

Comment: me too. it appears to hang after `f.fetch`

Answer (score 1):

There is a ruby wrapper for PageGlimpse available:

http://code.squidchunks.com/pageglimpse/

Unfortunately, the Terms of Use state that "You must not use or launch any automated system, including without limitation, "offline readers", "spiders," etc. to capture data provided by the Service."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gem [gastly](https://github.com/mgrachev/gastly).

`Gastly.capture('http://google.com', 'output.png')`