# Click on Print gives a screen shot to save in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-plugins, screenshot

I may fall under the list of possible duplicates but still i could not find the answer according to my req.In my rails application i have some web pages with a link of print option.
Now what i need is when i click on this print ,i should get a screen shot of the current web page and a popup box to save the image .Is there any plugin available for the same.

Also any queries for code are welcome

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for [phantomJs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs). Where you can alter the page HTML, manipulate CSS, insert & call javascript snippets, the way you need it.

Good documentation available and also you can find great deal of help in [stackoverflow-phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phantomjs)

Regards,
HBK

Comment: Thanx, i had used the same solution to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest that you use http://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/

if you want to make a screeenshot you have to work with the user env, so i suggest you look at this topic [How do I take screenshots of web pages using ruby and a unix server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726660/how-do-i-make-beautiful-screenshots-of-web-pages-using-ruby-and-a-unix-server)

Comment: ..i'll surely hav a look ..thanx