# Extracting background-images from a web page / Parsing HTML+CSS

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I'm building a sharing site which allows to **share webpage links** with Ruby on Rails.

I would like **to extract some representative images** for each page (as on *Facebook* when you share a link).

For now I use the [gem opengraph](https://github.com/intridea/opengraph) to parse `og:image` meta tag at first, and then I use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse the page content and retrieve all `<img>` tags `src` attributes. This give good results (except some decoration images, so I filter results by size...).

--

Now I would like to go further and parse css `background-image` property : websites logo are often display as background for a `<h1>` or a `<a>` tag.

I think about the following process:

- Parse HTML document with regex (something like `/background(-image)?:.../`) to find inline CSS
- Retrieve CSS stylesheets URLs with Nokogiri and parse these sheets with the same regex

... and absolutify URLs according to documents URLs.

--

**My questions are :**

- Do you think there is a better alternative ?
- Is there a library of some sort that can increase the performance of the process ?

  For example, if I could build a consolidated view of HTML+CSS, which allows me to access CSS properties via the DOM, I could access *only* the background-images of pre-selected HTML elements (h1,a,...) and limit the number of results.

Comment: Actually the image which is shown is defined in the `meta` tag with the property `og:image` and `img` tags are just used if it isn't defined.

Comment: @micha Yes I know, I parse it too. But the great majority of websites are not tagged with OpenGraph.

Comment: Not too familiar with Ruby on Rails, but I would avoid using regex to parse HTML or CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/522877

Comment: @Wex Hm yes I'm agree but according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/1089771) parsing a well-known subset of HTML (not arbitrary HTML doc) is a good job for regex. In my case I just want to match /background: url(...)/, and not nested tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parse the CSS of a web site, any images you are going to get back are going to be related to the user interface (sprites, backgrounds), not the actual content of the page.

I don't think it would be worth your while unless you're just trying to extract logos. In that case I would restrict to matches on class names/ids/paths containing the word "logo".

If you want to extract "representative images" from a page, I would just parse the image tags as you are doing then generate (and crop) a screenshot of the page as per: [How do I take screenshots of web pages using ruby and a unix server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726660/how-do-i-make-beautiful-screenshots-of-web-pages-using-ruby-and-a-unix-server)

How are you handling images that aren't in the raw HTML source?

In terms of libraries, I'm pretty sure nokogiri is the best thing out there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the link. It forwards me to Selenium, which could be interesting.

>> How are you handling images that aren't in the raw HTML source?
I don't, I only parse the raw HTML with Nokogiri. What are you thinking about ? Images loaded in DOM with JS ?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking sites about that load their image assets via javascript (lazyloading for example) or slideshows.